# Can I run git clone via an NPX tool

Tags: javascript, npm, npx

Im in the process of building a custom NPX tool which will add my custom npm package into a local hosted server,

I have as of right now a template of the structure id like to replicate when other users run my NPX command, something along the lines of

```
src
    index.js
build
    built_js.js
styles
    styles.css
```

I understand when it comes to npm packages ill have to run these commands separately which is fine but im wondering how i can rebuild this directory on command `npx create-my-app`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What file structure are you looking for?

Comment: @LeoDog896 hi sorry im in the process of re writing this question, im essentially trying to make a create-react-app style NPX tool and im curious how I can grab a template structure that ive already made to be created on the npx call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can!
try to use this package for it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-clone